# Predict function in R model

Tags: r, ggplot2, model

The R package growthcurver makes models with the function SummarizeGrowth which can be plotted with the plot() function. I want to plot the model with  ggplot, however, it doesn't work with the predict function.

```
library(growthcurver)

d <- growthdata

gc_fit <- SummarizeGrowth(d$time, d$A1)

gc_fit

plot(gc_fit)
```

Comment: ```df <- data.frame(t = gc_fit$data$t, N = gc_fit$data$N)``` --> then use ggplot2

Answer (score 1):

To get fitted values you can use `gc_fit$model$m$fitted()`:

```r
library(growthcurver)
library(tidyverse)

k_in <- 0.5
n0_in <- 1e-5
r_in <- 1.2
N <- 50

data_t <- 0:N * 24 / N   
data_n <- NAtT(k = k_in, n0 = n0_in, r = r_in, t = data_t)

gc_fit <- SummarizeGrowth(data_t, data_n)

tibble(t = data_t, pred = gc_fit$model$m$fitted(), N = data_n) |> 
  ggplot(aes(t, pred)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = N)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]